# How to use natestrauser:select with zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I'd like to know if anyone else has ran into this issue where if you add the zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css Meteor package before the natestrauser:select2 packages you end up with version 1.4.6 of zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css package and version 3.5.1 of the natestrauser:select2 package. However, if you install the natestrauser:select2 package before zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css package then you end up with version 0.1.1 of the zimme:select2-bootstrap3-css package and version 4.0.2 of the natestrauser:select2 package.

I'd like to have the latest of both packages. If this is a bug, I'm wondering if this is a known issue and is being worked on? If there is a solution, I'd like to know. Thanks!